# polymer restricting querySelector to shadow dom with inline template

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am trying to restrict querySelector to elements with the shadow dom created by a template with in the mainline of my web page. Here is a fragment of what I want to do:

```
<template id="userForm" is="auto-binding">
      <div id=contents>
           <my-element id='myElement>
      </div>
</template>
<script>
var userForm = document.querySelector('#userForm');
```

Now I would like to able to do something like:

```
var myElement = userForm.querySelector('#myElement');
```

or

```
var myElement = userForm.$.contents.querySelector('#myElement');
```

But neither of these work. If the template were contained within a custom element I could use:

```
this.$.contents.querySelector('#myElement);
```

All of this in aid of making sure I don;t select an element with the same id outside of the template.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I can be mistaken, but I think all you need to do is

```
 yourElement.shadowRoot.querySelector("#yourId");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David. I tried it but, using my example above,  userForm.shadowRoot is an undefined value.

Comment: @WillHopkins When you use `console.dir` to 'log' your element, do you see the shadowRoot property there? Or for that matter, are you running the polyfill or natively?

Comment: Oh wait a second, you're trying to get the shadowRoot of a template element, that's not gonna work probably no, because a template doesn't have a shadow DOM I am pretty sure... just take a look with a chrome inspector and see where the element actually is. And the `.shadowRoot` property will get you into any shadows you find.

Comment: I think the issue is I am looking for a handle to the instantiation of the template. I would have thought that userForm did this for me.

Comment: @WillHopkins: Are you running polymer, or just the template binding stuff, or are you making your own element? :P If you just want to bind data to your template you have to set the `.model` property on the template. But it all depends on what you wish to do. If you are **not** writing your own elements you don't need a template element like that at all.

Comment: I am using the template tag so I can use Polymer's data binding as documented here: [https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding].